# outputting characters to a spot in the terminal in python

Tags: python, text, terminal, character

I'm using python, and I was wondering how do I output characters to specific positions in the terminal (im using windows for this)

Answer (score 1):

The [Console](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) module has support for this (Windows only)

Comment: Of course who knows if this works with more recent versions of Windows.

Comment: @Rafe: I left that part for the OP to read from the documentation :-)